# PHP Mysql Image Display

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php gallery. I'm displaying image from mysql db using php, but my images are displaying in one by one. which means the first image in first row and second image in second row. but I want to display my image as 3 or 4 per row. what coding changes can I make. my php code as shown below.

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <table width='200'>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?><?php echo $res['imagename']?><?php echo"</a>"?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="news-image">
                        <?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?>
                        <?php echo'<img src='.$res['image'].' width="250" height="100">'?><?php echo"</a>"?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is a function to split an array into a collection of X items for you to loop through without having to keep counters (you can then use array_pad() on the last item in the list if you need padding)

```
if($array = array_chunk(mysql_fetch_assoc($result),4))
{
  foreach($array as $row)
  {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach($row as $col)
    {
      echo '<div class="item">' . $col['image'] . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting a table per image. At minimum, your code should be more like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php while($res etc...) { ?>
<td>
   <img src="<?php echo ......?>" />
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now you'll get all the images in a single row of a single table. Making it have multiple rows is left as an exercise to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
<?php 
include_once("config.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
?>
<table>
<tr>
<?
$varcount=0;
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $varcount++;
 if($varcount == 4) // Count of images per row. 3 or 4 
 {
      $varcount=0;
 ?>
  </tr><tr>
 <?
 } 
?>

 <td> 
 <table width='200'>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?><?php echo $res['imagename']?><?php echo"</a>"?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <div id="news-image">
 <?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?>
 <?php echo'<img src='.$res['image'].' width="250" height="100">'?><?php echo"</a>"?>
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td> 
 <?php
 }
?> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Marc B, He had many stuff inside table, like div, so i had not disturb the code.

Comment: You should also increment and reset `$varcount`.

Answer (score 0):

follow this example

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
$i = 1;
do{
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    //Num of Columns
    if( $i%3 == 0 ){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    $i++;
}while($i<=10);
?>
</tr>
<table>
```

will return the result something like you want..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
include_once("config.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <?php 
         $cnt = 0;
         while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         { 
        if($cnt == 3){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
          ?>
        <td>
    <table width='200'>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?><?php echo $res['imagename']?><?php echo"</a>"?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="news-image">
                    <?php echo"<a href='indimage.php?imageid=$res[imageid]'>"?>
                    <?php echo'<img src='.$res['image'].' width="250" height="100">'?><?php echo"</a>"?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
 <?php
$cnt++;
  }
 ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead output the images as a list of divs, or just divs, and then use CSS to show the images in two columns. Your layout should not be that hardwired.

```
<style>
    div.gallery {
        width: 650px;
    }
    div.gallery ul li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
    }
    div.image {
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <span class="image_title">Some title</span><br/>
                <img src="foo.png"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <span class="image_title">Another title</span><br/>
                <img src="bar.png"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <span class="image_title">Another title</span><br/>
                <img src="foo.png"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <span class="image_title">Another title</span><br/>
                <img src="bar.png"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <span class="image_title">Another title</span><br/>
                <img src="foo.png"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Your code should look something like:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>

<?php 
include_once("config.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <a class="image_title" href="indimage.php?imageid=<?php echo $res['imageid']?>"><?php echo $res['imagename']?></a><br/>
                <a href="indimage.php?imageid=<?php echo $res['imageid']?>"><img src="<?php echo $res['image']?>" /></a>
            </div>
        </li>
<?php
}
?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Solution i think you want that:
there are three pages.
1. index.php (which has the form for uploading the image)
2. upload.php (which save the image in directory and its path in database)
3. showimage.php (Finally, which will show the image)**

here is the code
**(index.php)**

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Choose File to Upload:</label><br />

<input type="hidden" name="id" />

<input type="file" name="uploadimage" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

**(upload.php)**

```
<?php
$target_Folder = "upload/"; // directory where images will be saved



$target_Path = $target_Folder.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

$savepath = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

    $file_name = $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];

    if(file_exists('upload/'.$file_name))
{
    echo "That File Already Exisit";
    }
    else
    {

        // Database 

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user_name","pasword","database"); // Change it if required
        //Check Connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to database" .     mysqli_connect_errno();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO image (id,image, image_name)
                    VALUES ('$uid','$target_Folder$file_name','$file_name') ";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "1 record added successfully in the database";
        echo '<br />';
        mysqli_close($con);

        // Move the file into UPLOAD folder

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'],     $target_Path );

        echo "File Uploaded <br />";
        echo 'File Successfully Uploaded to:&nbsp;' . $target_Path;
        echo '<br />';  
        echo 'File Name:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Type:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['type'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Size:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['size'];

    }
?>

<a href="showimage.php">Show Image</a>
```

**(showimage.php)**

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user_name","password","database_name"); // Change it if required

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM image " );


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '" width="200" />';
echo'<br /><br />';  
}


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Features**

It will check the names of file if that name file already exisit it will not uplad the file and alert the user.

**Database Structure**

id int(4) Auto Increment - image varchar(100) - image_name varchar(50)